# How to iterate through this text file faster?

Tags: python, parsing, dictionary

I have a file with lots of sections in this format:

```
section_name_1 <attribute_1:value> <attribute_2:value> ... <attribute_n:value> {
    field_1 finish_num:start_num some_text ;
    field_2 finish_num:start_num some_text ;
    ...
    field_n finish_num:start_num some_text;
};

section_name_2 ...
... and so on
```

The file can be hundreds of thousands of lines long. The number of attributes and fields for each section can be different. I'd like to build a few dictionaries to hold some of these values. I have a separate dictionary already which holds all the possible 'attribute' values.

```
import os, re
from collections import defaultdict

def mapFile(myFile, attributeMap_d):
        valueMap_d = {}
        fieldMap_d = defaultdict(dict)

        for attributeName in attributeMap_d:
            valueMap_d[attributeName] = {}

        count = 0
        with open(myFile, "rb") as fh:
            for line in fh:
                # only look for lines with <
                if '<' in line:
                    # match all attribute:value pairs inside <> brackets
                    attributeAllMatch = re.findall(r'<(\S+):(\S+)>', line)
                    attributeAllMatchLen = len(attributeAllMatch)
                    count = 0

                    sectionNameMatch = re.match(r'(\S+)\s+<', line)

                    # store each section name and its associated attribute and value into dict
                    for attributeName in attributeMap_d:
                        for element in attributeAllMatch:
                            if element[0] == attributeName:
                                valueMap_d[attributeName][sectionNameMatch.group(1).rstrip()] = element[1].rstrip()
                                count += 1
                        # stop searching if all attributes in section already matched
                        if count == attributeAllMatchLen: break

                    nextLine = next(fh)

                    #in between each squiggly bracket, store all the field names and start/stop_nums into dict
                    #this while loop is very slow...
                    while not "};" in nextLine:
                        fieldMatch = re.search(r'(\S+)\s+(\d+):(\d+)', nextLine)
                        if fieldMatch:
                            fieldMap_d[sectionNameMatch.group(1)][fieldMatch.group(1)] = [fieldMatch.group(2), fieldMatch.group(3)]
                        nextLine = next(fh)

        return valueMap_d
```

My problem is that the while loop that matches all the field values is noticeably slower than the rest of the code: 0.5s vs. 2.2s according to cProfile if I remove the while loop. I'm wondering what I can do to speed it up.

Comment: You could use a generator with a regular expression - if you provide some real samples one might be able to help you better.

Comment: How much slower it is?

Comment: @Jan I can't provide the original file but I'll see if I can create a sample myself.

Comment: @ElisByberi 0.5s vs. 2.2s. I edited the original post to add this info.

Comment: It has to be slow! Quoting from your post: `hundreds of thousands of lines long` @Colin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex is great when you need fancy pattern matching, but when you don't need that it can be faster to parse text using `str` methods. Here's some code that compares the timing of doing the field parsing using your regex vs doing it with `str.split`.

First I create some fake test data which I store in the `rows` list. Doing this makes my demo code simpler than if I were reading the data from a file, but more importantly, it eliminates the overhead of file reading, so we can more accurately compare the parsing speed.

BTW, you should save `sectionNameMatch.group(1)` outside the field parsing loop, rather than having to make that call on every field line.

Firstly, I'll illustrate that my code parses the data correctly. :)

```
import re
from pprint import pprint
from time import perf_counter

# Make some test data
num = 10
rows = []
for i in range(1, num):
    j = 100 * i
    rows.append(' field_{:03} {}:{} some_text here ;'.format(i, j, j - 50))
rows.append('};')
print('\n'.join(rows))

# Select whether to use regex to do the parsing or `str.split`
use_regex = True
print('Testing {}'.format(('str.split', 'regex')[use_regex]))

fh = iter(rows)
fieldMap = {}

nextLine = next(fh)
start = perf_counter()
if use_regex:
    while not "};" in nextLine: 
        fieldMatch = re.search(r'(\S+)\s+(\d+):(\d+)', nextLine)
        if fieldMatch:
            fieldMap[fieldMatch.group(1)] = [fieldMatch.group(2), fieldMatch.group(3)]
        nextLine = next(fh)
else:
    while not "};" in nextLine: 
        if nextLine:
            data = nextLine.split(maxsplit=2)
            fieldMap[data[0]] = data[1].split(':')
        nextLine = next(fh)

print('time: {:.6f}'.format(perf_counter() - start))
pprint(fieldMap)
```

**output**

```
 field_001 100:50 some_text here ;
 field_002 200:150 some_text here ;
 field_003 300:250 some_text here ;
 field_004 400:350 some_text here ;
 field_005 500:450 some_text here ;
 field_006 600:550 some_text here ;
 field_007 700:650 some_text here ;
 field_008 800:750 some_text here ;
 field_009 900:850 some_text here ;
};
Testing regex
time: 0.001946
{'field_001': ['100', '50'],
 'field_002': ['200', '150'],
 'field_003': ['300', '250'],
 'field_004': ['400', '350'],
 'field_005': ['500', '450'],
 'field_006': ['600', '550'],
 'field_007': ['700', '650'],
 'field_008': ['800', '750'],
 'field_009': ['900', '850']}
```

Here's the output with `use_regex = False`; I won't bother re-printing the input data.

```
Testing str.split
time: 0.000100
{'field_001': ['100', '50'],
 'field_002': ['200', '150'],
 'field_003': ['300', '250'],
 'field_004': ['400', '350'],
 'field_005': ['500', '450'],
 'field_006': ['600', '550'],
 'field_007': ['700', '650'],
 'field_008': ['800', '750'],
 'field_009': ['900', '850']}
```

Now for the real test. I'll set `num = 200000` and comment out the lines that print the input & output data.

```
Testing regex
time: 3.640832

Testing str.split
time: 2.480094
```

As you can see, the regex version is around 50% slower.

Those timings were obtained on my ancient 2GHz 32 bit machine running Python 3.6.0, so your speeds may be different. ;) If your Python doesn't have `time.perf_counter`, you can use `time.time` instead.

Comment: `while not "};" in nextLine:` -> this will scan each line from beginning to end (at least I think so, I don't know Python). So it might be (slightly) faster to only check the first two bytes of the line.

Comment: @Danny_ds I decided to leave that line as it is in the OP's code because I wanted to focus on the regex stuff, since that's the main thing that can be improved. Yes, `"};" in nextLine` does do a linear scan of the line, but that scan runs at C speed, so it's faster than if you tried to search for it using a Python loop. Sure, I could just check the first 2 chars of the line (they aren't bytes in Python 3, since it uses Unicode for text), eg by using the `.startswith` method, but then I'd have to assume there are no leading spaces, or pass the line through `.strip` first to trim off whitespace.

Comment: Yes, C speed and probably already in the L1 cache - that's why I used _slightly_ :) And using `.strip` would probably make it even worse, depending on the implementation. +1 anyway.

Comment: @Danny_ds Thanks! If we can be sure that the `"};"` is at the start of the line, it'd definitely be wise to use `.startswith` rather than `in`. OTOH, it's pretty common in Python text processing to `.strip` each line; I didn't bother in this code because when you call `.split` without a delimiter arg it removes all whitespace for you. The speed of stuff in Python can be weird, compared to a fully compiled language: an operation on a big string or list that runs at C speed may take roughly the same time as a simple explicit Python operation on a more elementary object.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thank you! I changed to .split for the while loop and I've reduced runtime from 2.2s to 0.7s :). Btw, I did not see any noticeable improvement with .startswith, nor after moving sectionNameMatch.group(1) outside of the loop. I made these changes anyway because it's the logical thing to do.

Comment: @Colin No worries. You may also get a bit of a speedup by parsing the `section_name_1 <attribute_1:value> ... {` lines using `.split`. If you do that,  you _might_ get a slight speed improvement by using `.endswith('{')` to detect those lines. Or you may be able to eliminate that test entirely: just skip blank lines and assume that a line is a  `section_name` line if you aren't currently inside a section.